# Tweepy Search w/ While Loop

Tags: python, while-loop, tweepy

This is driving me crazy. As you can see below I am *trying* to use a simple while loop to perform a couple of tweepy searches and append them into a data frame. For some reason however after pulling the first set of 100 tweets it just repeats that set instead of performing a new search. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
import csv
import pandas as pd
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

num_results = 200
result_count = 0
last_id = None 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Location', 'Followers', 'Text',    'Coorinates'])

while result_count <  num_results: 
    result = api.search(q='',count=100, geocode= "38.996918,-104.995826,190mi", since_id = last_id) 
    for tweet in result:
        user = tweet.user
        last_id = tweet.id_str
        name = user.name
        friends = user.friends_count
        followers = user.followers_count
        text = tweet.text.encode('utf-8')
        location = user.location
        coordinates = tweet.coordinates
        df.loc[result_count] = pd.Series({'Name':name, 'Location':location, 'Followers':followers, 'Text':text, 'Coordinates':coordinates})
        print(text)
        result_count += 1

# Save to Excel
print("Writing all tables to Excel...")
df.to_csv('out.csv')
print("Excel Export Complete.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The [API.search](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#help-methods) method returns tweets that match a specified query. It's not a Streaming APi, so it returns all data at once. 
Furthermore, in your query parameters, you have added `count`, that specifies the number of statuses to retrieve.

So the problem is that with your query you are returning the first 100 data of the complete set for each while iteration.

I suggest you to change the code in something like this

```
result = api.search(q='', geocode= "38.996918,-104.995826,190mi", since_id = last_id) 
for tweet in result:
    user = tweet.user
    last_id = tweet.id_str
    name = user.name
    friends = user.friends_count
    followers = user.followers_count
    text = tweet.text.encode('utf-8')
    location = user.location
    coordinates = tweet.coordinates
    df.loc[result_count] = pd.Series({'Name':name, 'Location':location, 'Followers':followers, 'Text':text, 'Coordinates':coordinates})
    print(text)
```

Let me know.

Comment: I tried excluding the 'count' parameter from my search query but that would only return 15 results. My understanding from the tweepy docs is that by including the 'count' parameter I can take that up to 100 and then make 15 requests to compile more results. I believe both those limits are enforced by the Twitter API, yes?

I also thought that the 'since_id' parameter was there to keep me from pulling the same top 100 results over and over?

I'm considering switching to the stream to pull the results but my goal is to gather a "random" selection of tweets and that'd inject some time bias.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, btw, where did you read about 15 requests with count parameter? Maybe you can try to remove the since_id param since  returns only statuses with an ID greater than (that is, more recent than) the specified ID.